# Emscripten link warning message: llvm_debugtrap

Tags: emscripten

I keep getting this warning message that says:

```
warning: unresolved symbol: llvm_debugtrap
```

I've looked the web for some sense on this but i coudlnt' find anything that cleared it for me. Does any one know what could cause this warning ?

Thank you